# como cargar dos modelos a una misma vista desde un tercer modelo que contenga ambos?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, .net

https://github.com/PequeCeci/Guava.git primero aqui les dejo el proyecto subido a github.. 
segundo aqui el codigo

```
    // este es el modelo que contiene ambos modelos
    namespace MyFirstWebsite.Models
    {
        public class Modelo
        {
            public List modeloReceta { get; set; }
            public Slide modeloSlide { get; set; }
```

```
        public Modelo(List<Receta> modelo1, Slide modelo2)
        {
            modeloReceta = modelo1;
            modeloSlide = modelo2;
        }
       }
}
```

`//luego este es mi controller 

    namespace MyFirstWebsite.Controllers
    {
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            private RepositorioRecetas _reposRecetas = null;
            private Modelo _modelos = null;
            public List modeloReceta = null;
            public Slide modeloSlide = null;`

public HomeController()
        {

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(_modelos);
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Recetas(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            var receta = _reposRecetas.GetReceta((int)id);

            return View(receta);
        }
    }
}

uno de los modelos tiene en data un repositorio de recetas el otro modelo es para volver dinamico a un slider...

Comment: Hola CeciPeque, ninguna de tus preguntas tiene respuesta aceptada, te sugiero leer [ask] para modificar tu pregunta y obtengas muy buenas respuestas, saludos.

Comment: esta mal hecha mi pregunta?, debo acortar el codigo?

Comment: voy a editarla..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haz que tu vista acepte el tipo de modelo `MyFirstWebsite.Models.Modelo` y cambia tu controlador por lo siguiente:

```
public ActionResult Recetas(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            var slide = new Slide{/*...*/};
            var receta = _reposRecetas.GetReceta((int)id);

            var modelo = new Modelo(receta, slide);
            return View(modelo);
        }
```

O también puedes usar el objeto ViewBag de MVC:

```
public ActionResult Recetas(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            ViewBag.Slide = new Slide{/*...*/};
            var receta = _reposRecetas.GetReceta((int)id);

            return View(receta);
        }
```

Y lo accedes desde tu vista como `@ViewBag.Slide`

Puedes encontrar mas información del objeto ViewBag en 
http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/viewbag-in-asp.net-mvc

Saludos.

Comment: hola mil gracias por responder, sabes ahora me subraya en rojo mi foreach loop creo que no acepta la parte que dijiste <pre> MyFirstWebsite.Models.Modelo<code>

Comment: antes tenia MyFirstWebsite.Models.Receta en mi view Receta y en el index MyFirstWebsite.Models.Receta[] xq tengo un repositorio pero en caso del modelo solo lo dejo modelo sin [] no?

Comment: Debes iterar sobre MyFirstWebsite.Models.Modelo.modeloReceta

Comment: cuando pongo MyFirstWebsite.Models. seguido del punto me aparecen tres opciones son: Modelo, Receta, Slide pero en Modelo tengo ambas clases instanciadas Receta y Slide... no se que me falta

Comment: Usa `MyFirstWebsite.Models.Modelo` y pon el punto después para que te muestre las opciones `modeloReceta` y `modeloSlide`

Comment: cual seria el codigo en Modelo a parte de instanciar esas dos clases Receta y Slide porque no me aparecen despues del punto? :(